# Работа с Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]По неизвестной мне причине не получает данные от сервера

```
public interface API {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/index.php")
    Call<String> getId(@Field("enter") String s);}
```

Отправить хочу Post запрос по адресу

https:// developerteam.ml//api/index.php

со строковым значением enter(key) s(value)

В ответ должен прийти ID

```
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl("https://developerteam.ml")
        .build();

private API api = retrofit.create(API.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Call<String> call = api.getId("1");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            ID = gson.toJson(response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Содержимое response.body:

> {serializeNulls:falsefactories:[Factory[typeHierarchy=com.google.gson.JsonElement,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25@ec799a3],
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter$1@2de44a0,
>   com.google.gson.internal.Excluder@54c2859,
>   Factory[type=java.lang.String,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13@38e7c1e],
>   Factory[type=java.lang.Integer+int,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7@ab02cff],
>   Factory[type=java.lang.Boolean+boolean,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$3@6f30acc].....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На сервере точно всё работает? Через postman проверь, выполняется ли запрос.

Comment: через postman приходит {"id":"50","password":"****"}

Comment: response.body() что содержит?

Comment: скорее всего ошибка в том, что ты ждешь в response.body() строку и пытаешь ее преобразовать в JSON. Но ты подключил GsonConverter который это уже делает за тебя. Т.е. ewsponse.body() должна быть не строкой а моделью, которая содержит ID и PASSWORD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

Интерфейс:

```
public interface API {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/api/index.php")
        Call<MyClass> getId(@Field("enter") String s);
}
```

Класс результата запроса:

```
public class MyClass{
    String password;
    int id;

    public int getID(){return id}
}
```

Запрос:

```
Call<MyClass> call = api.getId("1");
call.enqueue(new Callback<MyClass>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyClass> call, Response<MyClass> response) {
        ID = response.body().getID();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MyClass> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Не помогло, ID:0 и там только Call<MyClass> all (компилятор ругался и попросил поменять)

Comment: на что ругался и на что просил поменять?

Comment: Ругался на Call<String> изменил на Call<MyClass>

Comment: Попробуй изменить тип id с int на String – Nikotin N 5 минут назад

Comment: Изменил, теперь ID:null

Comment: а response.body() что содержит?

Comment: у меня работает с int id. Только я сделал запрос на http:// , а не на https://. Иначе выдавало ошибку при выполнении запроса (Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection)

Comment: Странности,прикрепил скрин то что выдает у меня

Comment: может бред, но попробуй Build->Clean Project

Comment: Не пойму, по какой-то причине response пуст, в отладчике не могу найти его даже, хотя на сервер реагирует на запросы

Comment: Нашел причину ошибки,ниже у меня был вызов getSharedPreferences и после вызова ID обнуляется а до вызова getSharedPreferences все сохраняется нормально

Comment: response просто теряется получается, дело в этом?

Comment: на сколько ниже? покажи код. Просто запрос выполняется асинхронно, и следовательно у тебя все идет в следующей последовательности : ты запускаешь выполнение запроса, далее начинается выполнятся код, который идет после запроса, а ID заполняется только когда выполнится запрос.

Comment: Добавил скрин, сразу после выхода из колбека значения переменных не сохраняются, они остаются только на момент выполнения чтения

Comment: попробуй перенести блок "if(mSettings.contains ... " в onResponse

Comment: перенес, сохраняет только внутри Callback'а, за пределами ID снова возвращает свое значение

Comment: Выдает null
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ID.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49082/discussion-between-nikotin-n-and-heaven).